# Financial evidence when entering UK

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration

When asked for financial evidence by immigration officers at the passport control when entering UK, can I submit the bank statements of the bank at my home country?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

[GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) (see p.2) does not make it an absolute requirement to have such paperwork with you when seeking entry, but in general it can be a good idea to have available the same documents when seeking entry as were supplied with your visa application. This advice is stated outright if you use the wizard at [Check if you need a UK visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa).

Bank statements do NOT have to be from a UK bank, or in Sterling. Most foreign national visitors would not have, or be able to open, UK bank accounts anyway.

Comment: Sorry but isn't this document for application of visit to UK instead of on arriving in UK?